# Does Google Play Service Leaderboard allow for negative numbers where negative is better?

Tags: google-play-services, leaderboard

The Google Play Services Leaderboard documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

does not provide an answer to if you can have negative numbers whereby:

-1.76% is a better score than -0.3% or 1.2%

Anyone know the answer?

For reference:

You can set numbers to be better when smaller:
[image: You can set numbers to be better when smaller]

I can add percentage sign
[image: I can add percentage sign]

But i'm just not sure if negative is possible considering:

"A score of 314159, for example, would be displayed as 3.14159, 3141.59, or 314159, depending on the decimal place you specified."

Would i put in -176? for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. 
I fired up Google play services and got a test leaderboard set up to try it out.

If you want -0.35 for example, you would ensure your leader board has 2 floating points
and you would pass it -35. This will create -0.35

If you wanted -3.45 you would pass it -335